# How should I write my tests so they don't fail?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm making some api endpoints using flask. I would like to know how to set up the tearDown for the tests so that two of the tests, namely for GET a specific report and DELETE a specific report, don't clash. Here's my code:

models.py

```
reports = [
 {
    "id": 1,
    "createdOn": "25-11-2018 09:57",
    "createdBy": 1,
    "type": "Red Flag Report",
    "location": "1,1",
    "status": "Resolved",
    "comment": "Act quickly"
 },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "createdOn": "26-11-2018 09:57",
    "createdBy": 2,
    "type": "Red Flag Report",
    "location": "2,2",
    "status": "Under investigation",
    "comment": "Don't let them get away with it"
 }
]

class ReportsModel():

  def __init__(self):
    self.db = reports

  def get_specific(self, report_id):
    return next(filter(lambda x: x["id"] == int(report_id), self.db), None)

  def delete(self, report_index):
    self.db.pop(report_index)
```

views.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource
from .models import ReportsModel

class Report(Resource):
  def __init__(self):
    self.reports = ReportsModel()

  def get(self, id):
    report = self.reports.get_specific(id)
    if report:
        return {"status": 200, "data": [report]}
    else:
        return {"status": 404, "error": "Report record not found"}, 404

  def delete(self, id):
    report= self.reports.get_specific(id)
    if report:
        self.reports.delete(self.reports.db.index(report))
        return {"status": 200,"data": [{"id": int(id), "message": "Report record has been deleted"}]}
    else:
        return {"status": 404, "error": "Report record not found"}, 404
```

test_reports.py

```
from unittest import TestCase
from flask import json
from flask_restful import request

from app import create_app
from app.api.v1.models import ReportsModel

app = create_app()

class TestReports(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.reports = ReportsModel()
    self.app = app.test_client()
    self.app.testing = True

  def test_get_specific_report(self):
    response = self.app.get('/api/v1/reports/1')
    data = json.loads(response.data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(data, {"status": 200, "data": [self.reports.get_specific(1)]})

  def test_delete_a_specific_report(self):
    response = self.app.delete('/api/v1/reports/1')
    data = json.loads(response.data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(data, {"status": 200, "data": [{"id": 1, "message": "Report record has been deleted"}]})
```

When I run the code on Postman it works perfectly. However, when I run the tests, the first test fails saying the expected status code is 404 and the message that the report is not found. This is the same result if I put the id 2 on both tests.
However, if I use 1 on one test and 2 on the other, the test passes.

Is there a something I can do to stop the tests from failing?

Edit: I should mention that my idea is to add a tearDown() so that I can reset everything for every test. Unfortunately, my idea so far has been:

```
def tearDown(self):
  self.reports = 0 #or some other value
```

But I haven't found an appropriate way to do it.

```
del self.reports
```

hasn't worked either.

Comment: First thing I noticed: the URLs are different, one is as a slash at the beginning, the other has not.

Comment: Sorry. I typed it wrong. I'll  add the slash.